# how to count the row which match a combined condition?

Tags: octave

For example, I have matrix m =

```
1 0 1 0 1 1;
0 1 0 1 0 1;
1 0 1 0 1 1;
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

I want count the number of row which first element m(i, 1) = 1 and third element m(i,3) = 1.

Use for loop will work. But, I hope there a easy way to do that. octave function sum SEEMS just support one condition.

Comment: Use for loop will work. But, I hope there a easy way to do that. octave function sum SEEMS just support one condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to find rows matching a certain condition in octave:

```m
m(:,1) == 1 # m(i, 1) = 1
m(:,3) == 1 # m(i, 3) = 1
```

You could combine multiple conditions using octave `&` (logical and) and  `|` (logical or) operators:

```
(m(:,1) == 1) & (m(:,3) == 1)
```

If you only want a number of matching roes, you could use a `sum` function:

```
sum((m(:,1) == 1) & (m(:,3) == 1))
```

Comment: Just test it, it works. Exactly what I want. thanks.